# Workflow move to another list

Tags: workflow, item, approval

I have an if statement which once satisfied, I want it to move to another list.

If each of these columns is either "Approved" **or** "Not Applicable" it should move the item to a new list.

This is what I have tried:

```
If Current Item:Column1 equals Approved
or Current Item:Column1 equals Not Applicable
and Current Item:Column2 equals Approved
or Current Item:Column2 equals Not Applicable
and Current Item:Column3 equals Approved
or Current Item:Column3 equals Not Applicable
and Current Item:Column4 equals Approved
or Current Item:Column4 equals Not Applicable
and Current Item:Column5 equals Approved
or Current Item:Column5 equals Not Applicable
and Current Item:Column6 equals Approved
or Current Item:Column6 equals Not Applicable

then Copy item in Current Item to List2
```

Sometimes one or two columns won't be set to Approved/Not Applicable and it will still copy the item.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I don't think the conditions you set is what you want to achieve. Do you mean: if (c1 equals A or c1 equals(NA)  ) and (c2 equals A or c2 equals(NA)  ) ? If yes maybe you should  try with Else condition

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't fully understand, "Approved" and "Not Applicable" are actually drop down answers for the columns. Each column needs to have either "Approved" or "Not Applicable" to copy it to the other list.

Comment: Maybe you could try, just as a test, to change the field from Choice to Text. Once the copy is done, if it's correct, you could switch back to choices fields.

Comment: @Gyonder is right. It looks like you want grouping of the OR conditions, each OR group separated by AND, but it won't evaluate correctly in this case. This will not group, will just evaluate them one after the other... Not really relevant. It will give true if even one of the 6 columns has the desirable value

Comment: Thanks for you the answers. @Gyonder, I understand what you mean now that statement is what I am after. But how would I go about 'grouping' as from my understanding I can't use brackets in workflows? I tried using nested If statements and they seem to have a similar error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I solved this by creating a calculated column with a AND/OR formula using brackets which allowed me to do my statement correctly. I then used the workflow and based it from my new calculated Yes/No Column.